# In Python, how do i read all columns where the values start with a certain string?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a table like:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a       b       c       [d
e       [f      g       h
i       j       k       l
m       n       o       [p
```

I want to load only the columns that contain a value that starts with left bracket  `[` .

So i want the following to be returned as a dataframe

```
col 2    col4
b        [d
[f       h
j        l
n        [p
```

Comment: Please put some codes for what have you tried so far.

Comment: You cant, I dont work in Python, but for any language you cannot look ahead and load only certain values from a file. Chances are you need to load all the values and then just store the one's matching your criterea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [7, '[8', 9]])
>>> df = df.astype('str')
>>> df
   0   1  2
0  1   2  4
1  4   5  6
2  7  [8  9
>>> df[df.columns[[df[i].str.contains('[', regex=False).any() for i in df.columns]]]
    1
0   2
1   5
2  [8
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to load only the columns that contain a value that starts with right bracket  [

For this you need
 [`series.str.startswith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df.loc[:,df.apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('[')).any()]
```

---

```
  col2 col4
0    b   [d
1   [f    h
2    j    l
3    n   [p
```

Note that there is a difference between startswith and contains. The docs are explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
s=df.applymap(lambda x: '[' in x).any()
print(df[s[s].index])
```

Output:

```
  col2 col4
0    b   [d
1   [f    h
2    j    l
3    n  [pa
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this, hope this works for you**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c','[d'], ['e','[f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l'],['m','n','o','[p']],columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
cols = []
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].str.contains('[',regex=False).any() == True:
        cols.append(col)

df[cols]
```

**Output**

```
    col2    col4
0   b   [d
1   [f  h
2   j   l
3   n   [p
```